# jQuery $.grep not working with Backbone "this.model.attributes"

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

This is a little strange. I've used the $.grep function countless times and now it doesn't function like normal.

I got 20 objects in the **this.model.attributes** variable of Backbone.

```
var daySubjects = $.grep(this.model.attributes, function(e){
     console.log(e);
     return e.dayIndex == dayIndex;
});
```

daySubjects doesn't return anything. And also the **console.log(e)** doesn't log anything. Even though the **this.model.attributes** seems to be an array like any other.

[image]

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Model` uses for key-value pairs. If you want to store a groups of data - use `Collection`.
Also I would suggest to use underscore methods for data manipulation and forget about jQuery `each`, `filter` etc.

```
var daySubjects = _.filter(this.collection.models, function(model) {
     return model.get('dayIndex') == dayIndex;
});
```

Comment: You are welcome, also you can use `this.collection.filter(function (model) { /**/ })` http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods